# My tag <form:erros path=" "/> isn't been reconized by eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have add all necessaries dependenceis and the lib was add in my file jsp.
So I don't know what else to do. Can anyone help me?

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.ortitle hereg/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" prefix="s" %>
```

```
<html>
head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form:form action="/casadocodigo/produtos" method="post" 
commandName="produto">

    <div>
        <label>Titulo</label> 
        <input type="text" name="titulo">
        <form:erros path="titulo"/>
            </div>
```

Comment: What's the *actual* error message, word for word? Is it the only message? Are you sure that the relevant taglib uri value is correct (it looks...unusual)?

Answer (score 0):

u added head tag like this 'head>' in jsp
change it to '' and try again